# Nested for-loops with Iterators?

Tags: java

I have the following code which uses nested for-each loops to traverse two ArrayList properties in the Job class and the Category class (as well as performing a little logic on the properties):

```
for(Object dobj : hospice.getCategorys()) {
    Category cat = (Category) dobj;
    for(Object pobj : cat.getJobs()) {
        Job job = (Job) pobj;

        if(job.getID() == id) {
            System.out.println(
                String.format("The Job %d belongs to the (%s) %s Category.", 
                              id, 
                              cat.getCode(), 
                              cat.getName()));

            catFound = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Is there anyway to make use of Java Iterators with this approach to create a more elegant and future-proof solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where did you learn such style but I bet every Java book for newbie did cover usage of for each loop, with appropriate use of generics.  I'll suggest you take a Java book, really read it once, as to learn how to use different facilities in the way it supposed to be.  And, please mind your spelling too.  It should be "categories" not "categorys".  Correct spelling does matter in maintainability.

Comment: What types do getCategorys() and getJobs() return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested loops with iterators is OK. But more elegant solution do not use explicit cast. Preferable solution get typed iterators:

```
for (Category cat : hospice.getCategorys()){
  for (Job job : cat.getJobs()){
    // logic here
  }
}
```

Note that in this case your methods should return typed objects `Category` and `Job` but not `Object`.

Comment: Ah okay.

I had getCategorys() returning a Collection. Replacing it with ArrayList<Category> works now. Thanks.